# Getting longest string with MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Just like there's `MIN()` and `MAX()` for numbers, is there anything to get the longest and shortest string/text?

I know about `length()` and `char_length()` but it just returns the length and not the text itself as value.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    LENGTH(c.name) AS catname,
    i1.ref, 
    MIN(i1.scost) as mincost, 
    SUM(i1.instock) as totalstock
FROM
    inventory i1
LEFT JOIN app.categories c ON i1.ref = c.ref
WHERE
    i1.date = ( SELECT 
                   MAX(i2.date)
                FROM
                    inventory i2
                WHERE
                    i2.ref = i1.ref AND 
                    i2.location = i1.location)
    AND i1.ref LIKE '%GS-5008PL%'
GROUP BY i1.ref
```

Edited to add: I even tried `COALESCE` but it doesn't work. Getting the max length would be great but atleast not null would be good.

Comment: You think your problem is more complicated than the example provided below, but I don't see why. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If table is small:

```
select your_column str, length(your_column) as len 
from your_table 
where length(your_column) = (select len 
                             from (select your_column str, length(your_column) as len 
                                    from your_table order by length(your_column) desc) 
                             where rownum < 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

are you mean is select one that has a field is longest in all recoreds?
if yes ,you can use

```
select * from table order by length(yourTextField) desc limit 0,1
```

Comment: Thats simple, but mine is alot more complex

Comment: Don't forget it won't be indexed - so performance will drop proportionately to result set size.

Comment: maybe  can add a field to record length(field),insert a record with field length ,you can index it.but this is not a good idea.